# Cannot load the CSS with NodeJS

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am beginner to NodeJS and facing problem in loading the CSS. Here is my code.

I am just creating a server running in `9090` port and loading the default `HTML` file.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var html = fs.readFileSync('./FirstApp/HtmlPages/index.html');
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(html);
        response.end();   
});
server.listen(9090);
```

On Loading `http://localhost:9090/` i am able to see the `index.html` html page but not able to see the linked `css` feature.(If i just load my `index.html` in browser i am able to see `css` feature but not through the server)

This is my simple HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="heading"><em>Login Page</em></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

`CSS` file

```
.heading {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I can see below warning in browser console

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:9090/css/styles.css".
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Make sure that you linked css with correct path

Comment: Path to the css file is proper i feel , because if i click on the path in VSCode , i am able to navigate to css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a created a web server that only serves a single file, the *index.html*. It does not read any CSS file from the local file system, and it does not serve any CSS files.

You could analyze the incoming request and see if the path of the request‘s URL points to the CSS file. If it does, read the CSS file instead of the HTML file and return it with the response.

Here's a working, modified version of your code (assuming that *styles.css* is located in a subdirectory of the dir where your index.html is located):

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if (request.url.match(/^\/css\//)) {
        var css = fs.readFileSync('./FirstApp/HtmlPages' + request.url);
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/css"});
        response.write(css);
        response.end();
        return;
    }
    var html = fs.readFileSync('./FirstApp/HtmlPages/index.html');
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(html);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(9090);
```

**Please note:** I would only do this for learning purposes, not for building an actual production web application. For that, I would use an existing HTTP server solution, for example [Express](https://expressjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking your file path is correct when linking to the css file. Try removing the `.` and have your path as `/css/styles.css` (but it comes down to ensuring that you have the correct path.

As a beginner, a common mistake might be that you forgot to save your css file after you made your edits.

Also, you should use the chrome developer tool (right click on page and inspect) to see if your css is already being applied to your html.

If you can show us the index.html code, that might help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but i have tried giving `.` also , but no luck

Comment: @Pradeephebbar try removing `rel="stylesheet"` from the link

Comment: I don’t think it’s a problem with the path to the CSS file. The problem is that you have a created a web server that only serves a single file, the index.html. It does not read any css file from the local file system, and it does not serve any css files.

Comment: @PatrickHund , So what modification do i need to do to include `css` also

Comment: Well, in your function, you could analyze the incoming request and see if the path of the request‘s URL points to the CSS file. If it does, read the CSS file instead of the HTML file and return it with the response. But I would do something like that only for learning purposes, not for building a real web application. For that, I would rather use an existing http sever solution, Express is most commonly used.

Comment: @PatrickHund , Actually path is pointing to css but if i read css instead of html , browser loading the html content instead of html page